# phpMyAdmin : Can login as non-root user without entering a password, despite the account having one

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using phpMyAdmin as a part of XAMPP. When I'm prompted with the login screen, I'm able to enter a non-root user account into the Username textfield, leave the Password textfield empty, and be able to login to the account. This is despite the fact that this user account does have a password attached to it. Even stranger, when I do provide the correct password for the user account, I'm given the following two errors and am unable to login:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'usernamehere'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'usernamehere'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

These same errors are also present when I attempt to login using a non-root user account through mysqli_connect() in a php file (whether I provide the password or not).

Comment: MySQL accounts are separate to local machine accounts. You are logging in as the anonymous user when you use a password-less, unknown account name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Phil says, you're logging in as the anonymous user. When connecting, all three of the username, password, and host need to match. Perhaps the users you're trying to connect as have a different host value from what you're connecting through. If one or more of those (username, password, and host) don't match, you'll either get the error message or logged in as the anonymous user.

Log in as the anonymous user and look on the main page for the connection information. In the "Database server" area, the first line tells you how you're connected (socket type means your host is 'localhost', TCP/IP networking can be %, or 127.0.0.1, or the actual IP address). Note the connection type, then log out and log back in as the root user. Then edit the users you've created, and modify their host value (or create a new user) to match the host you'll be connecting from. If the connection type was socket, make sure your host is defined with the host 'localhost'. If the connection is TCP/IP, then the exact IP address or the network wildcard `%` will work (since it's XAMPP, you most likely have MySQL and Apache running on the same machine, so using `127.0.0.1` is more secure than using the wildcard as it only allows local connections).

Answer (score -1):

- go to phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and edit this hope this will help.
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']= '';